# Determining birth year (~1837) and birthplace of Jeremiah Ryan from Drumwood, Tipperary, Ireland?

Tags: 19th-century, birth-records, ireland

I've been trying to track down when and where [Jeremiah Ryan](https://www.ancestry.com.au/family-tree/person/tree/120872934/person/201001876033/facts) was born. Over the years he has given a range of inconsistent birthdates while living in New Zealand. He died on 21 Jun 1907.

Names written in NZ/Ireland records: Jerry, Dermot, Joseph.

- The earliest age I've found was when he immigrated to NZ in 1875. His birthday would have been 1837.
- The age given at his death would have him born in 1827.
- The age given on his daughter Johanna Ryan's birth certificate would have him born in 1836.

His parents we believe were Michael Ryan and Bridget Burke. I have been unable to track down any information about his parents, so I'm wondering if this is correct.

His wife Mary Hayes was born on 24 May 1841, Drumwood, Tipperary. She was baptised in Sologhead and Oola, Tipperary.

All their children that were born in Ireland were in Drumwood and baptised in Sologhead and Oola.

Mary and Jeremiah were married 30 Jan 1862 (Witness: John Hayes and Johanna Dwyer) in Sologhead and Oola, Tipperary.

Mary's mother Johanna Fleming was born in Drumwood.

He may have had a brother Michael Ryan, but still researching this theory.

I'm wondering if Jeremiah was born outside of Drumwood.

Can anyone find any information that could help or the baptism itself?

---

I've found a possible child of Jeremiah's, if true it would have died early and would have been the first child. It was baptised in Sologhead and Oola, but they used the residence place of Moanmore (Ancery had it as Monvore). That could be the hint needed to solve this.

Joannes Ryan [John Ryan], 3 Dec 1862, Father: Jeremiah Ryan, Mother: Maria Hayes, godparent: Johanna Fleming.
https://search.ancestry.com.au/cgi-bin/sse.dll?viewrecord=1&r=5538&db=IrelandCatholicParish&indiv=try&h=4895158

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeremiah (aka Jerry aka Dermot aka Dimitrius) Ryan's baptism was on the 6th Feb 1832 in Cappawhite. He lived in Clouganiff aka Clonganhue, Tipperary. This is very close to Drumwood. His father was not Micheal but John. John died young and so did Jeremiah's oldest brother Michael so whoever filled out his death cert got confused.

https://www.findmypast.com.au/transcript?id=IRE/PRS/BAP/0282305